# Passing data structure as class function agrument

Tags: c++, class, oop, data-structures, linked-list

for this school project we had to make a linked list out of information we got from a file with this information.

```
Name:       ID:         GPA:
Alice       8234        2.7
mark        2672        3.0
Joanne      1234        3.7
John        3291        2.0
Tim         3212        3.8
Alford      1034        2.7
Benson      6290        2.5
Nancy       4234        3.7
Oscar       1672        1.0
Larry       1004        2.7
```

I got this information into a data structure. Now i am trying to use the id variable of the structure as the sorting key to the linked list, but i keep getting an error in my `void list::addnode(node key)` function with the variable `key`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node
    {
        string name;
        int id;
        float gpa;
        node *next;
    }*nodePtr; 
    node nodeinfo[10];

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr current;
    nodePtr temp;
class list {
public:

    list();
    void addNode(node);
    void deleteNode(int delData);
    void displayList();
};
list::list() {
    head = NULL;
    current = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}
void list::addNode(node key) {
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->id = key;

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL)
            current = current->next;

        current->next = n;
    }
    else
        head = n;
}
void list::deleteNode(int delData) {
    nodePtr delPtr = NULL;
    temp = head;
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL && current->id != delData) {
        temp = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current == NULL) {
        cout << delData << " is not in the list\n";
        delete delPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        delPtr = current;
        current = current->next;
        temp->next = current;
        delete delPtr;
        cout << "the value " << delData << "is no longer in the list\n";
    }
}
void list::displayList() {
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        cout << current->id << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
int main() {
    fstream datafile("studentdata.txt");
    list studentinfo;
    node student;

    if (!datafile)
    {
        cout << "Error!!";
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        datafile >> nodeinfo[i].name >> nodeinfo[i].id >> nodeinfo[i].gpa;
    }
    studentinfo.addNode(student);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By making the `head` (and other variables) global, you can only have one list. Why don't you make those variables members inside the `list` class?

Comment: Your indentation is a bit misleading. Use an autoformatter (most IDEs have one) to get the structure clearer.

Comment: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)... – and please don't typedef pointers, that's just information hiding without any real benefit.

Comment: The error is because `n->id` is an int type to which your trying to assign your  node type(`key`).

Comment: `n->id = key;` cannot work, `id` is of type `int`, `key` is of type `node`. If at all, you could do `*n = key`, but that would overwrite next pointer just set before as well. Why don't you just accept a `std::string` (as const reference) and an `int` as parameters?

Comment: Your `deleteNode` function doesn't adjust the `head` pointer if you have to delete the very first element in the list.

Comment: Just a recommendation: If you store the last node in an additional `tail` pointer, you don't have to iterate through the entire list to append a new node all the time...

Comment: @Aconcagua do you think i should get rid of the class or combine the data structure with the class?

Comment: The `list` class? You absolutely should keep it. As the nodes don't really make sense without the surrounding list, you might consider making them a nested class, possibly even private. `head` (and `tail`, if you decide to implement) should be a class member of `list`, `current` and `temp` should only be *local* variables of the functions you use them in. Something like `class list { struct node { /*...*/ }; node* head; node* tail; public: void deleteNode() { node* current; node* temp; /* ... */ } };`

Comment: As the two pointers would get member variables: Get used to implement the constructor's initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`) right from the start: `list::list() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) { }` – you prefer direct initialisation by value over default initialisation + separate assignment that way. For complex types, that can make a significant difference. Even more important: Some types *only* can be initialised that way (references, const members, non-default-constructible types).

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you are trying to assign a node type variable "key" to an int type data member "n.id". Instead you can either access the id from key by doing key.id, and then assign that to n.id or you can directly assign the parameter node "key" to the node n using n = key. As the two structs are of the same datatype, this should work, and is a more efficient way of assigning the values.

However this seems to still leave a lot of questions to be asked from your code. I am confused as to why you have chosen to use global variables for the pointers?

```
nodePtr head;
nodePtr current;
nodePtr temp;
```

This is likely to break your code down if you ever decide to make more than 1 list. Even if you don't intend to make another list, it is still better practice as it follows convention and makes your code more generalizable.

Also your main function is almost completely unintelligible. What is it trying to accomplish? you seem to be trying to read the file and save the result in the datafile, but then you are instead creating nodes using the student node which is left uninitialized. You should probably review the whole of your main function and try and focus of what kind of result you want.